# Using different compilers or compiler flags for different source files in the same object

Tags: makefile, fortran, gfortran, compiler-flags

I'm fairly new to makefiles and am currently running with the following one that came with the code and that I extended by the options `FFLAGS_EXT1`, `COMP_EXT1`, and `file1.F90` and `file2.F90`:

```
FC = gfortran
FFLAGS = -g -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -Dno_nans -I ../
FFLAGS_EXT1 = -g -fbacktrace -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -fbounds-check -fcheck=all -Wconversion -std=gnu -O3 -fmax-errors=5 -Dno_nans -I ../ # Stricter compiler flags
LDFLAGS =
OBJ_EXT = o
EXE_EXT = x
COMP = $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
COMP_EXT1 = $(FC) $(FFLAGS_EXT1) -c -o $@ $<
LINK = $(FC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

MAIN_MODULES = $(a list of file names without extensions)
OUR_MODULES = $(another list of file names without extensions)

# FORTRAN settings
.SUFFIXES: .F90 .$(OBJ_EXT)

# compilation rules
.F90.$(OBJ_EXT):
#   $(COMP)
    $(COMP_EXT1)

.PHONY: all
all: \
    program1.$(EXE_EXT) program2.$(EXE_EXT) ...

program1.$(EXE_EXT): \
    $(addsuffix .$(OBJ_EXT),$(MAIN_MODULES)) \
    $(addsuffix .$(OBJ_EXT),$(OUR_MODULES)) \
    file1.$(OBJ_EXT) \
    file2.$(OBJ_EXT)
    $(LINK)

...
```

This enables me to compile either all of the source files with `FFLAGS` or with the stricter `FFLAGS_EXT1` depending on the choice of the compilation rule.

What I'd like to get is: use `COMP` as default (there are also other programs apart from the defined `program1` which I must not break compatibility with) but use `COMP_EXT1` or respectively `FFLAGS_EXT1` specifically for `file1` and `file2` (the legacy code throws a lot of warnings I'd like to ignore and only focus on my new stuff - it is a fairly large project in total...).

I am aware of, e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554702/changing-cmake-compiler-flags-for-multiple-source-files-using-asterisks) post, but I'm totally unaware of how to implement this in my case.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the hint by @Matt, I figured out the this changed version would do the trick:

```
FC = gfortran
FFLAGS = -g -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -Dno_nans -I ../
FFLAGS_EXT1 = -g -fbacktrace -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -fbounds-check -fcheck=all -Wconversion -std=gnu -O3 -fmax-errors=5 -Dno_nans -I ../ # Stricter compiler flags
LDFLAGS =
OBJ_EXT = o
EXE_EXT = x
COMP = $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
LINK = $(FC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

MAIN_MODULES = $(a list of file names without extensions)
OUR_MODULES = $(another list of file names without extensions)

# FORTRAN settings
.SUFFIXES: .F90 .$(OBJ_EXT)

# compilation rules
.F90.$(OBJ_EXT):
    $(COMP)
file1.$(OBJ_EXT):
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS_EXT1) -c file1.F90 -o file1.$(OBJ_EXT)
file2.$(OBJ_EXT):
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS_EXT1) -c file2.F90 -o file2.$(OBJ_EXT)

.PHONY: all
all: \
    program1.$(EXE_EXT) program2.$(EXE_EXT) ...

program1.$(EXE_EXT): \
    $(addsuffix .$(OBJ_EXT),$(MAIN_MODULES)) \
    $(addsuffix .$(OBJ_EXT),$(OUR_MODULES)) \
    file1.$(OBJ_EXT) \
    file2.$(OBJ_EXT)
    $(LINK)

...
```

However, this seems to be quite cumbersome once there are many rules and many files. Simply using something like `$(COMP_EXT1)` did not work, as it failed with a no input file error.

Is there a way to shorten this construct?

Comment: Read [Target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html#Target_002dspecific) and [Pattern-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern_002dspecific.html#Pattern_002dspecific). And also [Computed variable names](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Computed-Names.html).

Comment: Thank you @Matt. I figured out above modification, yet I'm still not quite happy with it. Do you have any further hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, by all means, this is a matter of style. But let's try something:

```
# prefer simple variables over recursive ones...
FC := gfortran
FFLAGS := -g -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -Dno_nans -I ../
FFLAGS_EXTRA := -fbacktrace -fbounds-check -fcheck=all -Wconversion -std=gnu -O3 -fmax-errors=5

# ...unless we *do* require deferred expansion
COMP = $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(FFLAGS_$@) -c -o $@ $<
LINK = $(FC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

# this is a matter of choice but one-letter variables could be handy
O := o
X := x

# I assume both file1 and file2 are already mentioned here
MAIN_MODULES := $(a list of file names without extensions)
OUR_MODULES := $(another list of file names without extensions)

# use computed variables for maximum flexibility
FFLAGS_file1.$O := $(FFLAGS_EXTRA)
FFLAGS_file2.$O := $(FFLAGS_EXTRA)

.PHONY: all
all: program1.$X program2.$X ...

program1.$X: $(addsuffix .$O,$(MAIN_MODULES) $(OUR_MODULES))
    $(LINK)
program2.$X: ...
    $(LINK)

# it is recommended to use pattern rules instead of suffix rules
%.$O: %.F90
    $(COMP)

...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
However, I'm running into the following issue: if I define `OUR_FILES := file1 file2` after `OUR_MODULES := ...`, then define `FFLAGS_OUR_FILES.$O := $(FFLAGS_EXTRA)`, `FFLAGS_file1.$O := $(FFLAGS_EXTRA)`, and `FFLAGS_file2.$O := $(FFLAGS_EXTRA)`, and then define `program1.$X: $(addsuffix .$(OBJ_EXT),$(MAIN_MODULES) $(OUR_MODULES) $(OUR_FILES)) newline and tab $(LINK)`, `file1` and `file2` are not compiled with the additional flags.

Comment: @gothicVI I can't guess what you did wrong. Check compilation rule and COMP variable. FYI, the linking rule has nothing to do with compilation flags.

Comment: I'm an idiot... I wrote `$(FFLAGS_EXTRA)` instead of `$(FFLAGS_EXT)`. It's working now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to go a different route, namely to use [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) which is a library for well, quite some things programming in GNUmake. It offers a table data structure which is aimed at build config tasks like yours:

```
include gmtt-master/gmtt.mk

FC = gfortran
FFLAGS = -g -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -Dno_nans -I ../
LDFLAGS =
OBJ_EXT = o
EXE_EXT = x
COMP = $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
LINK = $(FC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

MAIN_MODULES = $(a list of file names without extensions)
OUR_MODULES = $(another list of file names without extensions)

# FORTRAN settings
.SUFFIXES: .F90 .$(OBJ_EXT)

# Construct a gmtt table. The one caveat is that we must escape the space characters in the
# second column until we select entries from the table.
define COMPILE_FLAGS_TBL
2
file1.$(OBJ_EXT) $(call spc-mask,-fbacktrace -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -fbounds-check -fcheck=all -Wconversion -std=gnu -O3 -fmax-errors=5)
file2.$(OBJ_EXT) $(call spc-mask,-fbacktrace -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -fbounds-check -fcheck=all -Wconversion -std=gnu -O3 -fmax-errors=5)
endef

# Special flags: "select column 2 from COMPILE_FLAGS_TBL where first column is string-equal to the target"
# ...and recover the space characters afterwards:
FFLAGS_SPECIAL =  $(call spc-unmask,$(call select,2,$(COMPILE_FLAGS_TBL),$$(call str-eq,$$1,$@)))

# compilation rules
.PHONY: all
all: foo.o bar.o file1.o file2.o

%.F90:
    touch $@

%.o: %.F90
    @echo flags: $(FFLAGS) $(FFLAGS_SPECIAL)
```

Output:

```
$ make
touch foo.F90
flags: -g -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -Dno_nans -I ../
touch bar.F90
flags: -g -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -Dno_nans -I ../
touch file1.F90
flags: -g -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -Dno_nans -I ../ -fbacktrace -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -fbounds-check -fcheck=all -Wconversion -std=gnu -O3 -fmax-errors=5
touch file2.F90
flags: -g -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -Dno_nans -I ../ -fbacktrace -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -fbounds-check -fcheck=all -Wconversion -std=gnu -O3 -fmax-errors=5
rm bar.F90 file1.F90 foo.F90 file2.F90
```

You can have more flexible file selection by using globs:

```
include gmtt-master/gmtt-master/gmtt.mk

FFLAGS = -g -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -Dno_nans -I ../
OBJ_EXT = o

# Construct a gmtt table. The one caveat is that we must escape the space characters in the
# second column until we select entries from the table.
define COMPILE_FLAGS_TBL
2
file1.$(OBJ_EXT) $(call spc-mask,-fbacktrace -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -fbounds-check -fcheck=all -Wconversion -std=gnu -O3 -fmax-errors=5)
file2.$(OBJ_EXT) $(call spc-mask,-fbacktrace -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -fbounds-check -fcheck=all -Wconversion -std=gnu -O3 -fmax-errors=5)
endef

define PATTERN_FLAGS_TBL
2
*_frobozz_[7-9].$(OBJ_EXT)  $(call spc-mask,-ffrobozz)
X_frabazz_*.$(OBJ_EXT)      $(call spc-mask,-ffrabazz -dwhatever)
endef


# Special flags: "select column 2 from COMPILE_FLAGS_TBL where first column is string-equal to the target"
# ...and recover the space characters afterwards:
FFLAGS_SPECIAL =  $(call spc-unmask,$(call select,2,$(COMPILE_FLAGS_TBL),$$(call str-eq,$$1,$@)))

# Very special flags: "select column 2 from PATTERN_FLAGS_TBL where target matches glob in first column"
# ...and recover the space characters afterwards
FFLAGS_VERY_SPECIAL = $(call spc-unmask,$(call select,2,$(PATTERN_FLAGS_TBL),$$(call glob-match,$@,$$1)))

# compilation rules
.PHONY: all
all: foo.o bar.o file1.o file2.o A_frobozz_8.o A_frobozz_6.o X_frabazz_mike.o X_frabazz_mandy.o

%.F90:
    @touch $@

%.o: %.F90
    @echo $@ flags: $(FFLAGS) $(FFLAGS_SPECIAL) $(FFLAGS_VERY_SPECIAL)
```

Output:

```
$ make
foo.o flags: -g -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -Dno_nans -I ../
bar.o flags: -g -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -Dno_nans -I ../
file1.o flags: -g -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -Dno_nans -I ../ -fbacktrace -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -fbounds-check -fcheck=all -Wconversion -std=gnu -O3 -fmax-errors=5
file2.o flags: -g -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -Dno_nans -I ../ -fbacktrace -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -fbounds-check -fcheck=all -Wconversion -std=gnu -O3 -fmax-errors=5
A_frobozz_8.o flags: -g -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -Dno_nans -I ../ -ffrobozz
A_frobozz_6.o flags: -g -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -Dno_nans -I ../
X_frabazz_mike.o flags: -g -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -Dno_nans -I ../ -ffrabazz -dwhatever
X_frabazz_mandy.o flags: -g -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -Dno_nans -I ../ -ffrabazz -dwhatever
rm X_frabazz_mandy.F90 A_frobozz_8.F90 bar.F90 file1.F90 foo.F90 A_frobozz_6.F90 file2.F90 X_frabazz_mike.F90
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, that's going too much into depth for this project. Yet I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: @gothicVI I took the "once there are many rules and many files" as an excuse to promote gmtt ;)